# Let order of a group be $108$. Show that there exist a normal subgroup of order $27$ or $9$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let order of a group be $108$. Show that there exist a normal subgroup of order $27$ or $9$.

Can we solve without sylow's throrems ? And by sylow's..i need both methods. Thanks

Comment: If $G$ acts on the set of four (or on3) Sylow $3$-subgroups, what can you say about the kernel of the action?

Comment: got your point. Thanks sir.

Comment: I cannot think of a way without Sylow theory :-(

Comment: yes, same prob sir , without sylow ,i also dint get solution yet.